# Heroku Postgres Database

Tags: heroku, rails-postgresql, heroku-postgres

I'm completely confuse about **Heroku Postgres Plan**. Please help.

When I check for PG info, using:

```
heroku pg:info
```

It's showing:

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL
Plan:        Basic
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-07-30 12:44 UTC
Data Size:   6.3 MB
Tables:      0
Fork/Follow: Unsupported

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 4
PG Version:  9.2.4
Created:     2013-08-06 05:17 UTC
Data Size:   10.7 MB
Tables:      13
Rows:        22346/10000 (Write access revoked)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
```

Here showing `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON`(free) have 13 tables. But in Paid database there is no table. Isn't it means paid database is not working?

I don't want to use that free database. Please help me to find a way to inset data into my paid database not into free.

I also tried by deleting free database from heroku database console. But then it shows `application error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "promote" the database you want to use.

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL
```

This will set the `DATABASE_URL` to the corresponding database.

More info [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)